# Zf2 change startup location

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I have zf2 on my web server and I cannot change the startup location in Apache. I copied .htaccess to public_html with changed path on /public/index.php but I have the problems with CSS styles and js. Can I make it in .htaccess without errors?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting or installed the project in a subdirectory,
# the base path will be prepended to allow proper resolution of
# the index.php file; it will work in non-aliased environments
# as well, providing a safe, one-size fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: can you show your .htaccess?

Comment: Post has been edited

Comment: and what is your problem? Can you be more precise?

Comment: @bartek_zet it shows index of site with all files

Comment: it can be something wrong with virtual host settings

Comment: you've got any ideas how to make it posible ?

Comment: do you have virtual host set? give us config

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a local development environment you don't need change the `.htaccess` at all, if you create a virtual host as @bartek_zet said.

So use the default `.htaccess` file, and create a virtual host like that:

```
# usually stored in /etc/apache/site-enabled/my-application.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

More information in [ZF2 documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html).

Comment: It' s normal hosting, I cannot edit Apache files but I made it in .htaccess and it works good. Thanks